# Visual SourceSafe. One project and two different (mixed) versions of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, version-control, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I have a really small team working with Visual Studio 2008 and Visual SourceSafe 2005 (Yeah, I know...)
A new developer just came in and he has Visual Studio 2012 on his machine.
He is not willing to install VS 2008 - who would?

So, what are our options here?

He tried to connect to VSS and download the solution but since he has a newer visual studio version all the project files need to be upgraded and those files where automatically checked out, which is not good. What I need is for him to get the solution and be able to check-out, check-in only aspx and c#/vb.net files, which are version independent.

Answer (score 0):

What about sharing the whole solution and in the meantime branching the project files (make the aspx and c#/vb.net files stay shared)?